# Variables passed from node won't display in EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am implementing a 'settings' page on my site, through which users can change their email address and password etc. On the settings page, I want to display the email address currently assigned to the user.

```
router.get("/settings", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    User.find({ "username": req.user.username }, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error finding user" + err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundUser);
            var emailAddress = foundUser.email;
            res.render("settings", { email: emailAddress });
        }
    })
})
```

Simple enough, the console.log prints the user details correctly like so:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e89b7b8a2936f4d3422ffc4,
    username: 'cafenero',
    email: 'cafe@nero',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

But for some reason, when I tried to use the date in my .ejs file, there variable is not showing!

```
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<%=email%>">
```

Value is just blank on the page! What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User.find({` returns array of data. To get the email, you need to access first element than email.

Change `var emailAddress = foundUser.email;` to `var emailAddress = foundUser[0].email;`

```
console.log(foundUser);
var emailAddress = foundUser[0].email;
res.render("settings", { email: emailAddress });
```

**Or Use `findOne` instead of `find`**

```
User.findOne({ "username": req.user.username }, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error finding user" + err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundUser);
            var emailAddress = foundUser.email;
            res.render("settings", { email: emailAddress });
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you I knew it had to be something simple. Answer was right in front of me too with the console.log output.